# Unable to start app with npm start

Tags: npm, angular

I have followed the instructions in https://angular.io/guide/quickstart and created the corresponding quickstart files and installed dependencies using npm install command. After that when I issue **npm start** command I am getting the following error.

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-32-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" `
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" '.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" 
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/sobin/AngularTuts/heroappbase/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Are you able to `npm run tsc`? Did `npm install` return any errors? Last time this happened to me there was a permission issue and a lot of things simply didn't install, including tsc.

Answer (score 1):

First, I tried just running this command in the command prompt:

```
concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite"
```

That worked. Then, in the package.json file, I replaced this line:

```
"start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
```

With this:

```
"start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
```

At that point,  `npm start`   worked normally. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to their docs, angular2 requires at least `node 5.x.x`

From their [site](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart):

> Verify that you are running at least node v5.x.x and npm 3.x.x by running node -v and npm -v in a terminal/console window. Older versions produce errors.

Looks like you are running `node v0.10.25`. Try upgrading.

To upgrade, you can use `nvm` which lets you switch easily between the versions. [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) on GitHub.